# Reading JSON array to listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-adapter

I'm pretty new to android dev and I need some help.

I'm building an agenda that loads the information from a JSON then a ListView is inflated with a custom adapter. I've done this and works just fine.

My problem is the following when I click a contact another Activity is loaded with more information about the user, using the same JSON. I debug it and it recieves the information like this:

```
Example Item: [{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","hobby":"Play soccer","address":"Kulas Light, Gwenborough","phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442"}]
```

Because I sent the information as a JSONObject I cast it to be a JSONArray, but when I pass that array to my requestComplete my app breaks.

The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

/**Main activity onclick listener*/

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    System.out.println("POSITION: " + position);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)JSONadapter.getItem(position);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    String pos_json = jsonObject.toString();
    intent.putExtra("pos_json",pos_json);


    startActivity(intent);

}
```

/**Info activity*/

```
public class InfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements JSONRequest.JSONCallback {

AdapterInfo JSONAdapter;
private ListView listInfo;
private JSONObject json_object;
private JSONArray arrayMain;

private ArrayList<String> jsonarray;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    try {
        json_object = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("pos_json"));
        arrayMain = array.put(json_object);


        System.out.println("Example Item: "+ arrayMain.toString());
        System.out.println(arrayMain.getClass().getName());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    requestComplete(arrayMain);


    this.listInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);


}



@Override
public void requestComplete(JSONArray array) {
    JSONAdapter = new AdapterInfo(InfoActivity.this,array);
    this.listInfo.setAdapter(JSONAdapter);


}
```

/**Adapter*/

```
public class AdapterInfo extends BaseAdapter{

private JSONArray array;
private Activity infoAct;

public AdapterInfo(Activity infoAct, JSONArray array){
    this.array = array;
    this.infoAct = infoAct;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(array == null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return array.length();
    }
}

@Override
public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
    if(array == null){
        return null;
    }else{
        return array.optJSONObject(position);
    }

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    JSONObject object = getItem(position);
    return object.optLong("id");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = infoAct.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row,null);

    }

    TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoName);
    TextView hobby = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoHobby);
    TextView address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoAddress);
    TextView phone = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoPhone);

    JSONObject json_data = getItem(position);
    if(json_data != null){
        try {
            String nombre = json_data.getString("name");
            String pasatiempo = json_data.getString("hobby");
            String direccion = json_data.getString("address");
            String telefono = json_data.getString("phone");

            name.setText(nombre);
            hobby.setText(pasatiempo);
            address.setText(direccion);
            phone.setText(telefono);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return convertView;
}}
```

/**JSONRequest*/

```
public class JSONRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

private JSONCallback callback;

public JSONRequest(JSONCallback callback){
    this.callback = callback;
}


@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

    URLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    JSONArray result = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();


        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            builder.append(line);
        }

        result = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

    }catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {


        try{


            if(br != null) br.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonArray);
    callback.requestComplete(jsonArray);
}


public interface JSONCallback{

    void requestComplete(JSONArray array);
}}
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the JSONObject. It has to do with the listInfo object being null and you are trying to call a method on it. Also, avoid System.out calls on Android; use Log instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
requestComplete(arrayMain);

this.listInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
```

`requestComplete()` uses `this.listInfo` instance but `this.listInfo` is null because it is set after `requestComplete()`. So you need to switch their order.

```
this.listInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
requestComplete(arrayMain);
```

It is better if you just put it right after call to `setContentView()` just to make sure `this.listInfo` holds valid `ListView` instance.